# HTACCESS remove .php extension except for certain url

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

So I have the following `.htaccess` file on my server which removes .php extension from all files, forces https and also removes www.:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

# remove www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

The problem is that I have an upload form for users to upload an image, so when they upload the images because the file gets redirects from /upload.php to just /upload it then becomes a GET request because of the redirect.

Is there any way I can stop this one file from removing the .php extension?

Comment: … or you could just make your form submit to the _correct_ URL to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an extra condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/upload\.php$
```

This condition will prevent your rules to be applied to your upload.php file.